# regex python \1 \2 possibility to add a string to the resulting Text

Tags: python, regex

I would love to know if it is possible to add a string to the result of the re.search operation in python in one line.

For example, I have the string:

```
strExamp = "Julia the happy girl from the 6th century"
```

The Result I want to achieve is:

> Julia the happy girl from the long-gone 6th century

my Code:

```
pattern = r"([a-zA-Z ]*),([/d][a-zA-Z ]*)",r"\1, myText+ \2" --doesnt work ofc 
result = re.search(pattern, strExamp)
```

What would be the way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match word characters without a digit `[^\W\d]+` in a group preceded by a space and assert what is on the right is a digit.

In the replacement, you could use the full match using `\g<0>` followed by a space and your replacement.

*Match*

```
^[^\W\d]+(?: [^\W\d]+)*(?= \d)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^\W\d]+` Match 1+ times a word char except a digit
- `(?:` Non capture group
   `[^\W\d]+` Match a space and 1+ time a word char except a digit
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `(?= \d)` Positive lookahead, assert a digit on the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGcIO7/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/DJjy0z)

*Replace with*

```
\g<0> long-gone
```

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"^[^\W\d]+(?: [^\W\d]+)*(?= \d)"
test_str = "Julia the happy girl from the 6th century"
subst = r"\g<0> long-gone"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Output

```
Julia the happy girl from the long-gone 6th century
```

Comment: @Eduard In the pattern `^[^\W\d]+( [^\W\d]+)*(?= \d)` you are repeating the capturing group itself, giving you the last value of the iteration and matching what is before that last value.  When you replace only with `\g<1>` you will loose what is matched before. See https://regex101.com/r/0N2L2S/1

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, Use:

```
import re

result = re.sub(r"(.*?)\s(\d+.*)", rf"\g<1> {my_text} \g<2>", strExamp)
print(result)
```

If `my_text = "long-gone"` and `strExamp = "Julia the happy girl from the 6th century"` this prints:

```
Julia the happy girl from the long-gone 6th century
```